# How React Native resolves ProgressBarAndroid?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs

Unlike other components of React Native, `ProgressBarAndroid` isn't exported from `react-native` module, rather you need to include it as a separate module like this

```
var ProgressBar = require('ProgressBarAndroid');
```

It is very much clear from the source code that the files are loaded from here
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/v0.25.1/Libraries/Components/ProgressBarAndroid

It works well when imported in the project but the same require() statement fails to find the module inside another third party library which I am writing.

Where could be the **resolution definition** for this file? Is it something to do with [Babel's React Native preset](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/babel-preset)? The same require() statement doesn't find the module with Node CLI tool.